# I assigned values to a list of strings with a dictionary. How can I sum these values?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
cards = ['2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','J','Q','K']

d = {'2':2,'3':3,'4':4,'5':5,'6':6,'7':7,'8':8,'9':9,'10':10,'J':10,'Q':10,'K':10}
```

How do I sum(cards)? Is it even possible -- I read that the dictionary only maps objects to other objects.

Comment: Quick question, why does your `cards` list not have a value for Ace?

Comment: I'm working on a Blackjack program and I'm trying to add one little change at a time and learn as I go :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if cards variable contains the labels of the cards you want to add then you can write the following code:

`sum_of_cards = sum([d[i] for i in cards]`)

Comment: Or just `sum(d[i] for i in cards)`

Answer (score 1):

Just because it exists:

```
sum(map(lambda x: d[x], cards))
```

Or even nicer with what @Chris_Rands suggested:

```
sum(map(d.get, cards))
```

Or even this solution using `__getitem__`:

```
sum(map(d.__getitem__, cards))
```

Comment: `sum(map(d.get, cards))`